# Subscription expiry reminder email

Tags: marketing-cloud

I need to send renewal reminders to customers regarding their subscription expiry date. I would be using automation studio (AS) for this.
Along with AS what other components I have to use.
Will it be suppression list & triggered send OR data filter & template based emails.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a test question?  If so, then [no soup for you](https://media.giphy.com/media/3xz2BtrwQ2wIBeciAw/giphy.gif)!

Comment: @AdamSpriggs It's not a test question. My apologies if the language of the question is sounding awkward.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs Actually I did some research and realised that it has to be either of the two options that I have mentioned in the question.
Hope this is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, the Automation components for something like this would be:

1. An [Import Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/import_activity/) to load the file from the FTP Import folder into the specified Data Extension.
2. A [Query Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) to select the audience to receive the reminder email.

   - This query will write to a Data Extension.
3. A [User-Initiated Send Definition](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_messages/how_to_create_a_user_initiated_email_interaction/) that uses the result of the first step as the sending audience.

   - The Email would need to be configured first.

Triggers are appropriate for transactional activities and are fired via API.

Suppression lists can be used in either configuration, but don't seem to be necessary with what you've described.

Comment: Thanks @Adam Spriggs!
Will any of this change if customer expiration date information is stored in a data file.

Comment: Updated my answer to include an Import Activity.